# Underlying hardware beneath virtual Com port

Tags: serial-port, usb, uart, libusb, libusbdotnet

I have a device connected to USB port via USB cable to my PC and in device Manager it says - > "XYZ corp Virtual COM port (COM A)"

Is this is same as Serial Com Port.?What is the underlying hardware under it both at device side and Host Side - a Uart or a USB or both at either end respectively?

Comment: *"Is this is same as Serial Com Port.?"* -- To an application program, yes.  The host side is a USB Host controller.  The adapter is USB Device controller with the functional equivalent of a UART and RS232 line-drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your USB device uses a driver that provides a serial port interface inside your computer. This means that other software can use the serial port APIs that Windows provides to connect to it and use it as a serial port.  That software doesn't need to know the details of your USB device; it just needs to know about using serial ports in Windows.  Windows ships with a driver that is often used to do this, and that driver is named usbser.sys.  Your device might be using usbser.sys or it might be using some other driver.

The serial data is transferred via your computer's USB port and a USB cable.  If you look at the signals on the USB cable, you will *not* see typical serial signals: you will see regular USB packets that just happen to be carrying that data needed for a serial port.

The USB device on the end of that cable might then translate that data into serial signals and act like a normal serial port, or that data might just be used directly inside the device.  Without a link to the product in question, it is hard to tell you more than that.

Comment: That's correct .I checked in the device manager and found that my device uses usbser.sys. driver.I understood that the PC is sending the data on a usual USB interface and on the device side I am recieveing it as a UART packets.I found some other controller in between the device and the PC' USB.Your explanation makes sense to me.Do you know to what component(sw or h/w) does the usbser.sys interacts and what lies above and below it.Is it like this : Application--->serial Port APIS--->usbser.sys.-->USB host controller driver-->usb Hardware???